# Unit test nested function parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

What is the best way to mock and test the inner method `onConfirm`?

```
public confirm(): void {
  this.confirmation.open({
   onConfirm: () => this.foo(this.bar('baz'))
  })
}
```

Comment: Try mocking `this.foo` and see if it's called?

Comment: hey @evolutionxbox i have already tried this, it is only triggered when a click is made, as in my case it is a dialog modal. I would like to separate unit and e2e tests and not trigger click events in the unit tests.